# Get the parent node of a node (Firebase)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i'm a beginner in android application, could anyone help me and show me how could i retrieve the generated id value node of the current user Id ? please find below my code. Thanks

[image]

```
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseDatabase mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference mDb = mDatabase.getReference();
FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
final String userKey = user.getUid();

    mDb.child("students").child(currentuser).getRef().addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String reference = dataSnapshot.getRef().toString();
        String userID = dataSnapshot.child("level").getValue(String.class);
        textViewStudentName.setText(reference);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please clear your requirements, why do you need this?

Comment: mDb.child("students").getRef() ?

Comment: Yes, i have students who are related to their parents Id, each parent (red ID) has oneToMany students (blue ID), and if i would retrieve the level of student i should get the parent node ID first then the student node ID which is the current user. mDb.child("students").child(<parent ID>).child(currentuser ID)

Comment: @S.Ramjit thanks for your reply, but if i use the "mDb.child("students").getRef()" i got the reference of students node (https://realtimeapp-8f118c.firebseio.com/students)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below to get `level`:

```
DatabaseReference fireReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("students");

fireReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for(DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            if(childSnapshot.hasChild(userKey)) {

                String userID = childSnapshot.child(userKey).child("level").getValue(String.class);

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```